Getting data from US Bureau of Labor Statistics
I am trying to get data from CPI data from US Bureau of Labor Statistics, which is accessible from here to my google sheets.
I used =IMPORTDATA and others (IMPORTXML and others) to get this list of CPI, but it does not work. I get the following error message: "Could not fetch url: https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.data.0.Current"
Please help!

thats a rly big array to import. import functions have its limits

running script yields:

Bureau of Labor Statistics
Access Denied
The BLS is committed to providing data promptly and according to established schedules. Automated retrieval programs (commonly called "robots" or "bots") can cause delays and interfere with other customers' timely access to information. Therefore, bot activity that doesn't conform to BLS usage policy is prohibited.
We apologize for any inconvenience. If you believe we have made an error, please contact us.

code could be:
function importBLSData() {
  const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace with your actual API key
  const url = `https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/CUUR0000SA0?registrationkey=${apiKey}`;
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  const options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
  };
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + response.getContentText());
    return;
  }
  
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  if (data.status === "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED") {
    const series = data.Results.series[0].data;
    const rows = [["Year", "Period", "Value"]];
    series.forEach(item => {
      rows.push([item.year, item.period, item.value]);
    });
    
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  } else {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}

with formula in A1:
=importBLSData()

but you will need API key: https://www.bls.gov/developers/home.htm

I had no idea how I go about doing that. Thank you sir for your guidance!

@user25204454 you will need to register https://data.bls.gov/registrationEngine/ and then generate your API key.
